# Can low-rank factorizations approximate quantum circuits?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Quantum circuits can be expressed as the matrix product of each gate in the circuit, where each gate is a unitary matrix (say) $G_i$. So, the whole circuit is $S = G_n G_{n-1} \cdots G_1$.

Since $S$ is unitary there isn't a non-lossy decomposition that reduces the rank (and would therefore be more efficient), but it seems like we might be able to get a close approximation, which could potentially speed up any circuit.

Note: I'm very new to QC so it's very likely this question has a lot of misunderstandings - I just want some help clarifying my knowledge! Thanks!